# How exactly the android assets are stored in device's storage

Tags: android, assets

Can anyone tell me , how exactly android assets are stored into device's storage after the instalation process ?

Answer (score 4):

They appear to be left in the APK and accessed directly from there. That is, unless you copy them somewhere.

Comment: I noticed that , when an android app is installed, It's apk file is copied to "data/app" directory. If I open it from there - just selecting view, I see assets folder which contains my files.

Comment: That is correct. The APK is copied there during installation, but the asset files are left inside it.

Comment: scottt ,would you like to add a link which describes the behaviour when an app is installed.